# Переход во вторую activity

Tags: java, android

Данное приложение сканирует штрих и qr код, как сделать так, чтобы после сканирования, результат сканирования выводился во второй `Activity`?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button, button1;
private TextView txtResult;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    txtResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
    final Activity activity = this;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Сканирование");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(result !=null){
        if(result.getContents() == null){
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else{
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            txtResult.setText("Результат сканирования: " + "\n" + result.getContents());
           // Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте результат в качестве параметра в `Intent`, который открывает новый `Activity`.

```
intent.putExtra("scanResult", scanResult);
```

В `Activity`, которая должна открыться в `onCreate`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getSerializableExtra("scanResult") != null){
    // Обрабатываем результат сканирования, который пережали из предыдущего Activity.
}
```

Comment: а можно более подробно? то есть конкретно куда это вставить?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы после сканирования я сразу (автоматически) переходил во второе activity, и там отображался результат

Comment: Ну так и вызывайте второй `activity` сразу после успешного сканирования..